# PHP json_decode: Object to Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array, json

The syntax for json_decode is:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Note the 2nd parameter `$assoc` which is optional and defaults to false.
When this parameter is `true`, `json_decode` converts objects to associative arrays.

My question is:
Is there every a case where you would **NOT** want to convert a returned object into an associative array?

Comment: I would add custom methods to allow serialisation and deserialisation (like the Serializable interface) for json. This allows proper construction of objects from json and json from objects.

Answer (score 5):

If a function returns an associative array, prior to PHP 5.4 you couldn't access its members directly as foo()['xxx']. However if it returns an object you can access the members as foo()->xxx.

Of course you may also have libraries that require you to access the return value as an object.

Comment: While this is no longer true, it was when the question was posted (and when `json_decode()` was written) so it's a good explanation for the default value.

Answer (score 2):

When you want it converted to an object...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always ask for an associative array and find it easier to work with than the object returned when $assoc=false.

But I would say the majority of other people's code I've seen (largely various web service client libraries) has used json_decode with $assoc=false and objects instead of associative arrays.  I think it's mostly a matter of preference though, as I've not seen any particular strong reason for choosing one way or the other.

Sorry for the non-answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion its a way to accentuate the difference between a list (in php expressed by a numeric array) and an entity (the object). This could be more readable, because one can read be the used accessor (`[]` or `->`) what kind of data is accessed.

Answer (score -3):

You need to pass an extra argument with true value.
json_decode($p,true);